# AWS Instance Image to New Instance - cannot access HTTP

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services

This may be a stupid questions, but I am lost.

I am trying to separate two websites (siteA and siteB) running on the same instance.
I created an image of the instance, launched another instance from that image and updated DNS zones for siteB with the new instance IP.

I can access siteA via ssh and http by old IP or its name.
I cannot access siteB http at all, not even by IP. I can access siteB via SSH using IP (or hostname, if that matters).

/etc/httpd/httpd.conf has listen 80
and virtual host configuration does not appear to be tied to any external IP.

Any advice?

Thank you!

Comment: ensure the new instance uses the same AWS Security Group (in the aws console)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I forgot to change security rules for access.
It used to be that quick-start would apply to new instances, not rules have to be added manually.